# Pick up only the most recent object associated with a person

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble with an exam question, I didn't get it correct on the exam but want to know what I am missing.

The Question:

> List the first diagnosis for each patient showing the patient's name,
>   diagnosis code and diagnosis date. If the patient has two or more
>   diagnoses on the earliest date, it's okay to just show one of those
>   diagnoses. Tables needed: encounters, patients, encounter_diagnoses,
>   diagnoses. Your result set should have four rows.

Here is what I had:

```
select p.patient_nm, max(e.start_dts)
from edw_emr_ods.patients p
join edw_emr_ods.encounters e
on p.patient_id = e.patient_id
join edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses ed
on e.encounter_id = ed.encounter_id
left join edw_emr_ods.diagnoses d
on ed.encounter_diagnoses_id = d.diagnosis_id
group by p.patient_nm
order by p.patient_nm asc
```

As you can see I did not include the Diagnosis code. (more on that later)  This returned 4 rows:

[image: 4 rows]

When I attempt to add the Diagnosis code I get 
"Column 'edw_emr_ods.diagnoses.code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
The only way I could figure out to remove this is to add code in the group by, since it is unable to sort the code and name together without it.  But this returns too many rows per patient.

[image: too many rows]

So my question is this **"How do I only pick up the name, date, and code of the most recent diagnosis?"**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `rownumber() over(...)` to answer your question :  "How do I only pick up the name, date, and code of the most recent diagnosis :

```
SELECT * FROM (
select p.patient_nm, e.start_dts row_number() over(partition by ed.code,p.patient_nm order by e.start_dts desc) as rn

from edw_emr_ods.patients p
join edw_emr_ods.encounters e
on p.patient_id = e.patient_id
join edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses ed
on e.encounter_id = ed.encounter_id
left join edw_emr_ods.diagnoses d
on ed.encounter_diagnoses_id = d.diagnosis_id ) AS T
WHERE rn =1
```

Comment: This does not work, it returns only the rows for Uncle Leo and their codes.  It also does not return the date.

Comment: Try adding `p.patient_nm` to the `PARTITION BY` list

Comment: This still fails to solve the problem... returning:
Cosmo Kramer NULL 2011-07-14 11:30:00 1
Elaine Benes NULL 2011-05-10 16:00:00 1
George Costanza NULL 2010-12-10 10:30:00 1
Uncle Leo NULL 2011-07-24 12:30:00 1
Uncle Leo 272.0 2011-07-24 10:15:00 1
Uncle Leo 401.9 2011-07-23 14:30:00 1
Uncle Leo 784.0 2011-07-24 10:15:00 1
Uncle Leo 786.05 2011-07-24 12:30:00 1
Uncle Leo 786.2 2011-07-24 10:30:00 1
Uncle Leo 786.50 2011-07-23 14:30:00 1
Uncle Leo 789.00 2011-07-24 10:30:00 1

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your input data and expected output

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh I figured it out, removing the "d.code" from the partition by solves the problem.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer one more time. Without any clear input data and expected output we are not able to help you.